# Opencart email configure error

Tags: php, email, configuration, opencart

I am using Opencart 2.3.0.2
I have added the following details under system/settings/mail

```
Mail Protocol: smtp
Mail Parameters: -fmyemail@gmail.com
SMTP Hostname : ssl://smtp.gmail.com
SMTP Username : myemail@gmail.com
SMTP Password : my email password
SMTP Port : 465
SMTP Timeout : 5
```

But Still I am not able to receive the email alert and get the following error
**"Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Network is unreachable) in ..../store/system/library/mail.php on line 167"** when i try to send the enquiry through contact form.

Could anybody please help me.

Comment: When the error occurred,Localhost or Server?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below settings in Opencart

```
SMTP Hostname: tls://smtp.gmail.com
SMTP Port: 587
```

If the above doesn't work try doing below with your existing settings.

Go to Gmail and login to the account that you used for your SMTP configuration.
Once logged in, go to “https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha”

Give it access to use GMail. Go back & try again submitting the contact form.